# Getting additional input of checkbox into array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple select checkbox with `others` option that user can checked as many option as they want and if what they want is not in the list of the option they can click `others` option and inserted the value.

I have problem in adding the inserted input value into the array.

Only value of the option listed got push into the array but not the inserted one.

```js
 let fruit_temp = [];
 $(document).ready(function() {
 

  $("#fruit").hide();
  $("#fruit_option").change(function() {
    if ($("#fruit_option").is(':checked')) {
      $("#fruit").show();
    } else {
      $("#fruit").hide();
    }
  });

  $('input[name="chk_fruit"]').change(function() {
    fruit_temp = [];
    $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
      if (this.value != 'others') {
        fruit_temp.push($(this).val());
      } else {
        fruit_temp.push($('#fruit_name').val());
      }
    });


  });
});
  const submit = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    //more formData
    formData.append('Fruit', fruit_temp);

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
  <label><b>Favourite Fruit</b></label><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Apple"> Apple</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Manggo"> Manggo</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Honeydew"> Honeydew</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Orange"> Orange</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" id="fruit_option" value="others"> Others</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="fruit" class="row">
      <label><b>insert fruit name you wish </b></label><br>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <input class="from-control" type="text" id="fruit_name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- more form field -->
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the value of the input to `fruit_temp` when the "Others" checkbox is checked, instead of when the form is submitted.

You should instead store whether the checkbox is checked in a variable, then, when the submit button is clicked, check whether the variable is `true`. If it is, push the value of the input to the array, process the array, then check again whether the variable is `true`. If it is, remove the last item from the array.

```js
let fruit_temp = [];
var isOtherChecked = false;
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#fruit").hide();
  $("#fruit_option").change(function() {
    if ($("#fruit_option").is(':checked')) {
      $("#fruit").show();
    } else {
      $("#fruit").hide();
    }
  });

  $('input[name="chk_fruit"]').change(function() {
    fruit_temp = [];
    $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
      if (this.value != 'others') {
        fruit_temp.push($(this).val());
      } else {
        isOtherChecked = true;
      }
    });
  });
});
const submit = () => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  //more formData
  if (isOtherChecked) {
    fruit_temp.push($('#fruit_name').val())
  }
  formData.append('Fruit', fruit_temp);
  if (isOtherChecked) {
    fruit_temp.pop() //we know the last item has to be the value of the input field
  }

  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
  <label><b>Favourite Fruit</b></label><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Apple"> Apple</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Manggo"> Manggo</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Honeydew"> Honeydew</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Orange"> Orange</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" id="fruit_option" value="others"> Others</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="fruit" class="row">
      <label><b>insert fruit name you wish </b></label><br>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <input class="from-control" type="text" id="fruit_name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- more form field -->
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pushing the value on the changed event there is no value. You can push the value on *focusout* event of the input:

```
$('#fruit_name').on('focusout', function(){
    fruit_temp.push($('#fruit_name').val());
});
```

```js
 let fruit_temp = [];
 $(document).ready(function() {
 

  $("#fruit").hide();
  $("#fruit_option").change(function() {
    if ($("#fruit_option").is(':checked')) {
      $("#fruit").show();
    } else {
      $("#fruit").hide();
    }
  });

  $('input[name="chk_fruit"]').change(function() {
    fruit_temp = [];
    $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
      if (this.value != 'others') {
        fruit_temp.push($(this).val());
      } else {
        $('#fruit_name').on('focusout', function(){
           fruit_temp.push($('#fruit_name').val());
        });        
      }
    });


  });
});
  const submit = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    //more formData
    formData.append('Fruit', fruit_temp);

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
  <label><b>Favourite Fruit</b></label><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Apple"> Apple</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Manggo"> Manggo</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Honeydew"> Honeydew</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Orange"> Orange</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" id="fruit_option" value="others"> Others</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="fruit" class="row">
      <label><b>insert fruit name you wish </b></label><br>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <input class="from-control" type="text" id="fruit_name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- more form field -->
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the user enters something into the input, clicks another checkbox, then focuses back on the input and changes a value, you will get more than one value in the `fruit_name` array.

Comment: @Spectric, that point is logically correct to me!

Comment: How would it? If I entered something and I changed it later, I would want the last value in the input to be processed.

Comment: @Spectric, I have answered mine while you have yours, let OP decides which best suits him!!!

Answer (score 0):

simply change the checkbox value attribute !

```js
const
  myForm    = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, chkOption = document.querySelector('#chkOption > input')
, fruitOpt  = document.querySelector('#fruit-option')
  ;
// init clear
myForm.reset()
            
chkOption.onchange =_=>
  {
  fruitOpt.classList.toggle('notVisible', !chkOption.checked)
  }
myForm.fruit_name.oninput =_=>
  {
  chkOption.value = myForm.fruit_name.value.trim()
  }
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()

  let result = Array
    .from( new FormData(myForm).entries())
    .reduce((a,[k,v])=>{if (k==='chk_fruit') a.push(v);return a},[])
    .join(', ')

  console.log( result )
  setTimeout(()=>
    {
    console.clear()
    myForm.reset()
    fruitOpt.classList.add('notVisible')
    }, 2000);
  }
```

```css
label,
button {
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : both;
  margin  : .1em;
  }
.notVisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  }
  
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:30% !important; width:70%; }
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Apple"   > Apple    </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Manggo"  > Manggo   </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Honeydew"> Honeydew </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Orange"  > Orange   </label>
  <label id="chkOption">
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="" > 
     other 
  </label>

  <label id="fruit-option" class="notVisible" >
    <b>insert fruit name you wish </b><br>
    <input type="text" name="fruit_name" placeholder="other fruit">
  </label> 

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```